# lvreduce : "No directory, logging in with HOME=/"

Tags: filesystems, lvm, data-recovery

I wanted to reduce my `home` LVM size so I executed the following commands :

```
sudo umount -fl /dev/ubuntu-vg/home
lvreduce --size -4G /dev/ubuntu-vg/home
```

As the last command didn't work (apparently the partition was used elsewhere), I decided to roll back :

```
sudo mount -fl /dev/ubuntu-vg/home
```

But, After doing this, my personal `/home/Jack` folder disappeared !

Now, when I log in, I have the following message :

```
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
```

Is there a way to get my account back ?

Regards

Comment: what does `lvdisplay` show?

Comment: It lists the home partition

Comment: am I right in assuming that you did not shrink your filesystem first?

Comment: Well, I used the -f option as it didn't work normally (the partition was apparently still used)

Answer (score 2):

I think what happened is you did try to reduce lvm size before getting filesystem shrink. Should do `resize2fs` to shrink filesystem before `lvmreduce`

Do not mount it. You might end up getting filesystem corruption.

Check if you have vg metadata backup it is under
 `/etc/lvm/` when you modify vg it puts there as default since you have access to there check it first as your first attempt to recover.

If backup did not work you can try recovering by extending LV back to its original size so give it that 4G back.

You can try `4G` but to be safe you can give all available I guess.

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/home
```

Comment: rather than resize2fs you should use `lvreduce -r`.  Then it handles the FS resize for you.

Comment: If the metadata backup doesn't work out, enlarging the volume is likely to fail, because it might not use the same extents as before.

Comment: @PoX : it should be with `-l` and not with `-L`

Comment: @zakaria you are rigth fixed it